# How to check dump of crash in linux

Tags: linux, exploit

I started exploit-exercize fusion challange (link: https://exploit-exercises.com/fusion/) and i want to examine the core dump .

I'm in level 00 , it realy easy to make the program crash but hoe can i see the dump with the dietels on the crash so i will build an Exploit?

I already try `ulimit -c unlimited` and then crush the program and then check `sudo gdb --core=/core --quiet` , but it returns `no core file founds`

I tried also `su -s 'ulimit -c unlimited' root` and then crash the program and then check `gdb --core /tnp/cores`  but again nothing was there.

How can i exemine the crash? (apperently it's not possible to just open and run the program from gdb , so it must be somehow throo system core dumps)

Comment: If you use a systemd system, try running `coredumpctl` and see if the cores appear there.

Answer (score 0):

Simple usage of GDB, to debug coredump files:

```
gdb <executable_path> <coredump_file_path>
```

Comment: The q. is How do i generate this coredump file?

Comment: 1.core file dumped in the  same directory as the executable is running, 2.check the current directory write permission.. if both are fine                      3. check /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern. That may redirect core dumps to another directory, and that directory must be writable